# Numpy: signed values of element-wise absolute maximum of a 2D array

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, max

Let us assume that I have a 2D array named `arr` of shape (4, 3) as follows:

```
>>> arr
array([[ nan,   1., -18.],
   [ -1.,  -1.,  -1.],
   [  1.,   1.,   5.],
   [  1.,  -1.,   0.]])
```

Say that, I would like to assign the signed value of the element-wise absolute maximum of `(1.0, 1.0, -15.0)` and the rows `arr[[0, 2], :]` back to `arr`. Which means, I am looking for the output:

```
>>> arr
array([[ 1.,   1.,  -18.],
   [ -1.,  -1.,  -1.],
   [  1.,   1., -15.],
   [  1.,  -1.,   0.]])
```

The closest thing I found in the API reference for this is [numpy.fmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fmax.html#numpy.fmax) but it doesn't do the absolute value. If I used:

```
arr[index_list, :] = np.fmax(arr[index_list, :], new_tuple)
```

my array would finally look like:

```
>>> arr
array([[ 1.,   1., -15.],
   [ -1.,  -1.,  -1.],
   [  1.,   1.,   5.],
   [  1.,  -1.,   0.]])
```

Now, the API says that this function is

> equivalent to `np.where(x1 >= x2, x1, x2)` when neither x1 nor x2 are NaNs, but it is faster and does proper broadcasting

I tried using the following:

```
arr[index_list, :] = np.where(np.absolute(arr[index_list, :]) >= np.absolute(new_tuple), 
                              arr[index_list, :], new_tuple)
```

Although this produced the desired output, I got the warning:

> /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal

I believe this warning is because of the NaN which is not handled gracefully here, unlike the `np.fmax` function. In addition, the API docs mention that `np.fmax` is faster and does broadcasting correctly (not sure what part of broadcasting is missing in the `np.where` version)

In conclusion, what I am looking for is something similar to:

```
arr[index_list, :] = np.fmax(arr[index_list, :], new_tuple, key=abs)
```

There is no such `key` attribute available to this function, unfortunately.

Just for context, I am interested in the **fastest possible** solution because my actual shape of the `arr` array is an average of (100000, 50) and I am looping through almost 1000 `new_tuple` tuples (with each tuple equal in shape to the number of columns in `arr`, of course). The `index_list` changes for each `new_tuple`.

---

Edit 1:

One possible solution is, to begin with replacing all NaN in `arr` with `0`. i.e. `arr[np.isnan(arr)] = 0`. After this, I can use the `np.where` with `np.absolute` trick mentioned in my original text. However, this is probably a lot slower than `np.fmax`, as suggested by the API.

---

Edit 2:

The `index_list` may have repeated indexes in subsequent loops. Every `new_tuple` comes with a corresponding rule and the `index_list` is selected based on that rule. There is nothing stopping different rules from having overlapping indexes that they match to. @Divakar has an excellent answer for the case where `index_list` has no repeats. Other solutions are however welcome covering both cases.

Comment: Does the **number of elements** in `index_list` change for each new_tuple?

Comment: @Divakar, yes, the number of elements in `index_list` changes. This `index_list` is actually calculated by using the `new_tuple` with some extra magic in the statements preceding the one discussed above.

Comment: So, do we have the list of all `index_list` and all `new_tuple` before going into the said loop?

Comment: I will have to run the loop once and create a large dictionary of those values. I don't have them in advance. I would prefer to not risk a memory_error.

Comment: What's the loop iteration count (typically, if not an absolute number)?

Comment: almost 1000. I mentioned this in my context paragraph in the end. Is that you question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that list of all `index_list` has no repeated indexes:

**Approach #1**

I would propose more of a vectorized solution once we have all of `index_lists` and `new_tuples` stored in one place, preferably as a list. As such this could be the preferred one, if we are dealing with lots of such tuples and lists.

So, let's say we have them stored as the following :

```
new_tuples = [(1.0, 1.0, -15.0), (6.0, 3.0, -4.0)] # list of all new_tuple
index_lists =[[0,2],[4,1,6]]  # list of all index_list
```

The solution thereafter would be to manually repeat, replacing the broadcasting and then use `np.where` as shown later on in the question. Using `np.where` on the concern around the said warning, we can ignore, if the `new_tuples` have non-NaN values. Thus, the solution would be -

```
idx = np.concatenate(index_lists)
lens = list(map(len,index_lists))

a = arr[idx]
b = np.repeat(new_tuples,lens,axis=0)
arr[idx] = np.where(np.abs(a) > np.abs(b), a, b)
```

---

**Approach #2**

Another approach would be to store the absolute values of `arr` beforeand : `abs_arr = np.abs(arr)` and using those within `np.where`. This should save a lot time within the loop. Thus, the relevant computation would reduce to :

```
arr[index_list, :] = np.where(abs_arr[index_list, :] > np.abs(b), a, new_tuple)
```

Comment: Thank you. The Approach #2 would not be appropriate. There is nothing stopping from the index list having repeats like this: `index_list = [[0, 2], [4 , 1, 6], [1, 7, 9], [5, 7, 8]]`. The negative values from `new_tuple` will be overwritten in subsequent loops with the repeat indexes.

Comment: The approach #1 is a great idea. It should save computation time for the `np.where` statement. My question is only, how would that handle repeats in `index_list`? It probably won't matter but do you have experience with repeats?

Comment: I just checked and for approach #1, only the last `new_tuple` corresponding to any repeated `index_list` values is considered. I didn't say anything about the `index_list` generation in my question assuming it to be non-relevant but both your methods would not work in the presence of repeats.